# Does swallowing skin off of lips break your fast?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I have read that if you swallow the skin from your lips intentionally, knowing that your fasting, then your fast is broken, but i also read that if it is difficult to eject it from your mouth then it wont break your fast, after reading this, i knowingly swallowed it but now after reading more, i dont know if my fasting is still valid or if i should make up a day after ramadan or even 60 days. What should i do?